# Delete columns but keep specific values pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm sure this is in SO somewhere but I can't seem to find it. I'm trying to remove or select designated `columns` in a `pandas df`. But I want to keep certain values or `strings` from those deleted `columns`.

For the `df` below I want to keep `'Big','Cat'` in `Col B,C` but delete everything else.

```
import pandas as pd

d = ({
    'A' : ['A','Keep','A','Value'],           
    'B' : ['Big','X','Big','Y'],
    'C' : ['Cat','X','Cat','Y'],
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

If I do either the following it only selects that row.

```
Big = df[df['B'] == 'Big']
Cat = df[df['C'] == 'Cat']
```

My intended output is:

```
       A    B    C
0      A  Big  Cat
1   Keep          
2      A  Big  Cat
3  Value
```

I need something like `x = df[df['B','C'] != 'Big','Cat']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you want to keep only some values and have empty string on ohters

Use `np.where`

```
keeps = ['Big', 'Cat']
df['B'] = np.where(df.B.isin(keeps), df.B, '')
df['C'] = np.where(df.C.isin(keeps), df.C, '')


    A     B     C
0   A     Big   Cat
1   Keep        
2   A     Big   Cat
3   Value
```

Another solution using `df.where`

```
cols = ['B', 'C']
df[cols] = df[cols].where(df.isin(keeps)).fillna('')

    A     B     C
0   A     Big   Cat
1   Keep        
2   A     Big   Cat
3   Value
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC

Update

```
df[['B','C']]=df[['B','C']][df[['B','C']].isin(['Big','Cat'])].fillna('')
df
Out[30]: 
       A    B    C
0      A  Big  Cat
1   Keep          
2      A  Big  Cat
3  Value
```

Comment: Sorry @Wen. I need to keep everything in `Col A` and `'Big,Cat'` in `Col B,C` in the one `df`

Answer (score 1):

You can filter on column *combinations* via NumPy and [`np.ndarray.all`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.all.html):

```
mask = (df[['B', 'C']].values != ['Big', 'Cat']).all(1)

df.loc[mask, ['B', 'C']] = ''

print(df)

       A    B    C
0      A  Big  Cat
1   Keep          
2      A  Big  Cat
3  Value
```

Comment: I think OP wants to 'keep' only some values in the columns, not filter rows

Comment: @RafaelC, Thank you, have updated (with a similar idea).

Comment: Nice one dude :-), I get confused at the start, sorry for the miss leading

Answer (score 1):

Or this:

```
df[['B','C']]=df[['B','C']].apply(lambda row: row if row.tolist()==['Big','Cat'] else ['',''],axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
       A    B    C
0      A  Big  Cat
1   Keep          
2      A  Big  Cat
3  Value
```

Comment: Little bit over kill but still work nice one man , vote for you

Comment: Yw: -)  have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a concise version:

```
df.loc[df['B'] != 'Big', 'B'] = ''
df.loc[df['C'] != 'Cat', 'C'] = ''
print(df)
```

Output:

```
       A    B    C
0      A  Big  Cat
1   Keep          
2      A  Big  Cat
3  Value
```